# "Ghost" MouseMove event in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, events, mouseevent, mousemove

I have a custom control that updates two `NumericUpDowns` with the current mouse coordinates by handling the `MouseMove` event.

However I have experienced a strange case where the `MouseMove` event is fired even when this should not happen (I have turned off my wireless mouse and disabled the trackpad). So, `MouseMove` happens even if the mouse does not move.

I've made a simple check and verified that between these "ghost" `MouseMove` events the position of the mouse pointer does not change. I exploited this to my advantage to make sure that the method handling the event is only called when the pointer has actually moved, so I have been able to meet the requirements for my application.

However, I am still puzzled, as I don't understand what could fire MouseMove events when all mice/trackpads are disabled. Looking at the call stack in Visual Studio, it seems to me that the firing of the `MouseMove` event is "genuine", as if the mouse really moved, not as if it was fired by some other part of the application (e.g. to simulate a `MouseMove`).

Any suggestions on what might be the reason for this? Thank you!

EDIT: Following King King's suggestion, I modified the code to print a string every time the message for `MouseMove` is detected. I've noticed that when the mouse is off and the pointer is hovering the control, the string is printed when I Alt-Tab to switch between application. Perhaps this has something to do with the application being redrawn?

Comment: to know if there is an actual MouseMove, try overriding the `WndProc` and add this code `if(m.Msg == 0x200) System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Mouse MOVE!!!!!!!!!!");`, I think there won't be any `Mouse MOVE!!!!!...` printed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately "Mouse MOVE!!!!!" are printed.

If I don't do anything, nothing is printed. However when I switch between applications with Alt-Tab (on Windows 7), "Mouse MOVE!!!!!" is printed a few times. This only happens when the mouse pointed is hovering the control.

Could this be caused by the window being redrawn for some reason?

Comment: two ideas: [A] do you have any touch screen equipment? they get reported as mouse movements under windows 7 and sometimes need to be filtered out [B] are the updowns linked to screen co-ords or app co-ords. probably not, but maybe the co-ord change of app co-ords is having an effect?

Comment: Hi Nick, no touch screen equipment involved. The values of the updowns comes from app coords normalized between 0 and 1 that are scaled to the size of the control and rounded to the nearest integer before being displayed. I don't see this as the possible cause of the problem.

Comment: I've noticed this exact behavior before in my applications as well.  It first came to my attention five years ago when I was writing an auto-logout function for a system.  WM_MOUSEMOVE (with no change in position) would intermittently fire even when the system wasn't being used causing the application to think the program was being used when it actually wasn't.  That was in VB.Net 2005 Express in WinXP Pro.  I never figured out the source and ended up removing WM_MOUSEMOVE as a source for "activity" in the algorithm.  I don't have a solution for you, but you are definitely not alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows synthesizes a fake WM_MOUSEMOVE message sometimes.  This in particular will happen on a focus change from one window to another.  The window that gets the focus also gets the move message.  Seeing this happen when you use Alt+Tab is an excellent lead that this is indeed the source of the message.

This is all entirely intentional.  It ensures that the other train of messages triggered by WM_MOUSEMOVE will occur.  In particular WM_NCHITTEST and WM_SETCURSOR.  So that the correct mouse cursor shape is displayed.  Otherwise affected in Winforms by the Control.Cursor and Application.UseWaitCursor properties.

You'll have to live with this, do make sure that this is never a problem.

Comment: "Otherwise affected in Winforms by the Control.Cursor and Application.UseWaitCursor properties."
That doesn't quite make sense to me. Are you giving us a solution here?