# Why MouseMove event occurs after MouseUp event?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, visual-c++

In `WindowsForms` I just added event handlers as follows:

```
    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"=> Form1_MouseDown, Clicks: {e.Clicks}, Location: {e.Location}");
    }

    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"=> Form1_MouseUp, Clicks: {e.Clicks}, Location: {e.Location}");
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"=> Form1_MouseMove, Clicks: {e.Clicks}, Location: {e.Location}");
    }
```

And the output is:

```
=> Form1_MouseMove, Clicks: 0, Location: {X=17,Y=21}
=> Form1_MouseDown, Clicks: 1, Location: {X=17,Y=21}
=> Form1_MouseUp,   Clicks: 1, Location: {X=17,Y=21}
=> Form1_MouseMove, Clicks: 0, Location: {X=17,Y=21}
```

You can see that all events occurs in the same location, So my question is why is there a `MouseMove` event after `MouseUp` event?

Also I tried similar code in WPF and `MouseMove` event **NOT** occurred.

And I tried similar code in C++ and `MouseMove` event **NOT** occurred:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
     ...

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        OutputDebugString(L"WM_MOUSEMOVE\n");
        break;

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        OutputDebugString(L"WM_LBUTTONDOWN\n");
        break;

    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        OutputDebugString(L"WM_LBUTTONUP\n");
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the mouse moving? If so it'll generate movement events.

Comment: It is incorrect to assume that the order of messages arriving in a Windows callback function matches your physical actions.  It is not a FIFO queue.

Comment: @JeffD. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31509391/7206675) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#queued-messages-1)

Comment: You must always assume that the OS might synthesize a MouseMove notification, even if the mouse did not move.  It sets off a sequence of other messages that affect the cursor shape for example.  In this case it happens because the mouse capture state changed.  Add `this.Capture = false;` to the MouseDown event handler to see a difference.

Comment: The links you posted in response to @Jeff's comment just support what he wrote. As for your question itself, "Why?" questions are generally primarily opinion-based, and this is no exception. You need to ask Microsoft why a WM_MOUSEMOVE is generated following a WM_MOUSEUP. That said, your code should always be prepared to deal with a mouse-move, and either Windows or .NET might generate one in this scenario to work around buggy programs that don't e.g. reset their cursor state on a mouse-up (most programs will check cursor state on mouse-move).

Comment: Note that this isn't an issue unique to .NET. For example, here's a Chromium bug report complaining about the same thing: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161464. I would not be surprised if there's some compatibility code in Windows that is being triggered for Winforms programs, as well as Chromium-based code, that does this to help those programs work better. Again, your code should always be able to deal with mouse-move events, so it shouldn't be a problem to get extras.

Comment: You should see `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_LBUTTONUP`, `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, which translates to `MouseDown`, `MouseClick`, `MouseUp`, `MouseMove`. There's no `MouseMove` before a `MouseDown` is the mouse is held still. You do want to know whether the mouse has moved in between the moment it has been pushed down and the moment it has been released. Other MouseMove events are generated before you can read the MouseUp event. So, you can flag the MouseUp and use the flag in the MouseMove event that follows.

Comment: This happened to me but only in dev console device toolbar using either ipad air, ipad pro, or surface. ipad mini works ok. just weird. mousemove gets triggered first instead of mousedown. anyone know the reason why? large screen device types only?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your mouse had previously been focused on a separate window, then clicking on a new window and shifting the focus of the mouse will generate a mouse move event (even if the mouse didn't move immediately before or after you clicked your mouse).

Here is a link to a similar StackOverflow response
["Ghost" MouseMove Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222437/ghost-mousemove-event-in-winforms?rq=1)

Answer (score 7):

This is because the mouse capture by the `MouseDown` is released on `MouseUp`. And this extra `MouseMove` may be to ensure the cursor position. As a workaround you can do this

```
        Point LastLocation = Point.Empty;

        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("=> Form1_MouseDown, Clicks: " + e.Location + ", Location: " + e.Location + "");
        }

        private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("=> Form1_MouseUp, Clicks: " + e.Location + ", Location: " + e.Location + "");

        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (LastLocation != e.Location)
            {
                LastLocation = e.Location;
                Debug.WriteLine("=> Form1_MouseMove, Clicks: " + e.Location + ", Location: " + e.Location + "");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the intended behavior and will also be trigger whenever app is being switched (Eg: Alt+Tab).

You should go with workaround as suggested by @VishnuBabu's workaround. And to ignore initial mousemove trigger, you can **get the current position of cursor once window is loaded** instead of setting the LastLocation to Empty.